# PHP JWT authorization token expired. using refresh token how to assign new auth token

Tags: php, api, jwt, refresh-token

I am developing a simple REST API using JWT token Authentication and PHP. I am generating an access token and a refresh token with different algorithms. when I am passing the required parameters to my API, it is successfully giving me $jwt and $refresh_token and I am able to pass it to the next api call and check if the $jwt is valid and provide the response.
My JWT token presently has 1 minute expiry time and the refresh token is having expiry time of up to 3 days.
This is my login-api.php output when user provides username and password.

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "jwt": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbGtrbi5pbi8iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTM5MTQxOTgsIm5iZiI6MTY1MzkxNDIwOCwiZXhwIjoxNjUzOTE0MjU4LCJhdWQiOiJteXVzZXJzIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJpZCI6MTksIm1vYmlsZW51bWJlciI6IjcyMDc0OTM1OTUiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImtsdfejkmrtLmNvbSJ9fQ.2zsW91tEG5K32DKQ3e7fD2uVELRC9wXqjGIkKg-ah70",
    "refresh_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzM4NCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbGtrbi5pbi8iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTM5MTQxOTgsIm5iZiI6MTY1MzkxNDIwOCwiZXhwIjoxNjUzOTM1Mzk5LserererfmNvbSJ9fQ.fz27rvXlH5IM-D5MuXncKZx0DY6amcprJE-CAU7AV4YRAsv94e1FPx-UpzT11fdA",
    "message": "user logged in successfully."
}
```

when i access the other api with the provided jwt after 1 min expiry I am checking if jwt is expired and if not providing response or else checking if refresh token expired if not renewing the jwt token and want to provide the response. but i am getting error. below is the code i have written.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){
    
    $all_headers = getallheaders();
    $data = new \stdClass();
    $data->jwt = $all_headers["Authorization"];
    
    $databody = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    if(!empty($data->jwt)){
        
            try{
                $decoded_data = JWT::decode($data->jwt, new key($secret_key,$usr_algorthim));
                http_response_code(200);
                $ruserid = $decoded_data->data->id;
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "status" => 1,            
                    "message" => "We got JWT Token.",
                    "user_data" => $decoded_data,
                    "user_id" => $ruserid
                ));
                
            }catch(Exception $ex){
                if($ex->getMessage() == "Expired token"){
                    try{
                        $decode_refresh = JWT::decode($databody->refresh_token, new 
                        key($usr_refresh_algorthim,$usr_refresh_algorthim));
                        http_response_code(200);
                        $payload_info =array(
                            "iss"=>$iss,
                            "iat"=>$iat,
                            "nbf"=>$nbf,
                            "exp"=>$exp,
                            "aud"=>$aud,
                            "data"=>$user_arr_data
                         );
                        
                        $new_jwt = JWT::encode($payload_info, $secret_key, $usr_algorthim);
                        $ruserid = $decoded_data->data->id;
                        echo json_encode(array(
                            "status" => 1,
                            "jwt"  => $new_jwt,
                            "message" => "We got JWT Token.",
                            "user_data" => $decoded_data,
                            "user_id" => $ruserid
                        ));
                    }
                    catch(Exception $exrefresh){
                        if($exrefresh->getMessage() == "Expired token"){
                            http_response_code(500);                       
                            echo json_encode(array(
                                "status" => 0,            
                                "message" => "Your Event Expired. ". $ex->getMessage()
                            ));
                        }  
                        else{
                            echo "i am here";
                        }                      
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                   

                }
                // http_response_code(500);
                // echo json_encode(array(
                //     "status" => 0,            
                //     "message" => $ex->getMessage()
                // ));
            }
        

      

    }
}
```

it is always printing echo "i am here"; eventhough the refresh_token is not expired. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Inspect `$exrefresh` to see what the message is

Comment: Signature verification failed i am getting

Comment: So… does that help you then? `decode` can [fail for many reasons](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/d28e6df83830252650da4623c78aaaf98fb385f3/src/JWT.php#L90)

Comment: yes $decode_refresh = JWT::decode($databody->refresh_token, new 
                        key($usr_refresh_algorthim,$usr_refresh_algorthim)); 
i am passing $usr_refresh_algorthim  twice instead of secret key..hmm my bad it got me frustrated for more than 4 hrs.